# Design of a standalone class/framework requiring external data

Tags: java, config, software-design

For the sake of an example, I have a class called `FileIdentifier`. This class:

- Has the method identify which accepts a `File` and returns a `String` representing the type.
- Requires external data since new file formats are a possibility.

How could this class be written so it could used in any project while remaining unobstrusive? Overall, how is this aspect usually handled in standalone frameworks that require configuration?

Comment: Is this a case where your code is data-driven, perhaps by a database of any sort, or where you actually want to easily add new strategies for performing variations of the task by writing additional code.

Comment: @erickson: I'd say yes for data-driven. The idea here would be to add new values to avoid having to use hard-coded variables and having to recompile each time something new comes along. In the big picture, what I'd like to know is how this sort of thing is handled usually when it comes to frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

That all depends on how you identify the file type. From your question I would assume that it's not a process as trivial as parsing for the file extension...

That said maybe you could just use an external XML file, or INI, or db table etc. that maps file types and just have the class read that data and return whatever... (You would actually want to use a few classes to keep things clean.) That way only the external data would need to be updated and the class remain unchanged.

Comment: Yes, in the example the idea is to id files using [file signatures](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html). With respect to the external file could I just instruct a programmer to place it in the classpath or should a more flexible approach be provided?

Comment: Placing the file in a classpath would be fine and for added flexibility I would take erickson's suggestion from the comment on the OP to implement a strategy pattern for interfacing with the source of the file mapping information.

Answer (score 2):

Try with a [chain of responsibility](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternChain.aspx).

Each instance in the chain is from a different class that manages a single file type. The file is passed down in the chain, and as soon as an instance decides to manage it, the chain stops and the results are returned back.

Then you just would have to build the chain in the desired order (maybe with more common file types at the top), provide default classes that manages some file types in your framework. This shoud be also easy to extend in your applications, it's just a matter of writing another subclass of the chain that manages your new user-defined file types.

Of course your base class for the chain (the Handler, as called by dofactory.com) could provide useful protected methods to its subclasses in order to make their work easier.